# How to use DateRangePicker directive in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I want to use DateRangePicker in Angular 2 where a user can select the date range and on submit button it should be saved in any variable.

I am using DateTimePickerDirective but unable to get selected date range.

Please help me with HTML and .ts code

Daterange website:
http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: Refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378686/how-i-use-daterangepicker-js-in-my-angular-2-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this wrapper to implement in angular 2
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-daterangepicker

```
npm install --save angular2-daterangepicker
```

After installing this, add all dependencies like jquery,bootstrap.. as npm packages
in .html

```
 <input daterangepicker
                (selected)="dateSelected($event)"
                [options]="pickerOptions" type="submit"
                [disabled]="disabled"
                value="{{datelabel}}"
                class="form-control btn btn-primary inputField"/>
```

in .ts

```
 @Output() selectedDate:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(false);

      public disabled:boolean;

      private pickerOptions: Object = {
        'showDropdowns': true,
        'showWeekNumbers': true,
        'timePickerIncrement': 5,
        'autoApply': true,
        'startDate': '04/27/2016',
        'endDate': '07/27/2016'
      };

      private formats:Array<string> = ['DD-MM-YYYY', 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'DD.MM.YYYY', 'shortDate'];
      private format:string = this.formats[0];
      private startdate: Date = new Date();
      private enddate: Date = new Date();
      private datelabel: string = 'Please choose a date';
      private selected: any;

      constructor() {
        this.disabled = false;
        this.selected = {};
      }

      private dateSelected(message: any) {
        this.selectedDate.emit(message);
      }
```

Comment: I am very new in Angular 2...
May you provide a small example?